# using reference in iteration of array

Tags: c++, c++11

```
vector<int> nums;
.....

//Case- A
for(int& i : nums){ 
....
}

//Case- B
for(int i : nums){ 
....
}
```

Will there be any difference in performance in Case- A and Case- B

Comment: Question #1: is that loop a bottleneck? Question #2: did you profile both variations?

Comment: Maybe.  Benchmark it and find out.

Comment: There probably won't be with a simple type like `int`, but if it were a complex class there could be. Only way to know for sure is to benchmark.

Comment: From semantic point of view, you should compare `int` with `const int&` and not with mutable `int&`.

Comment: Did you consider to check `for(const int& i : nums){ ` also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It certainly depends on what the body of the loop does.

With no body to the loop, both will just completely discard the entire loop.

There's nothing different about the code that can be generated in either case.  The `&` case-A has the most likelihood of being able to discard needless operations (like copying values).  But obviously the semantics are different when it comes to modifying `i`.